# Property attribute

Tags: c#, typeconverter

I have a component like this

```
public class MyDatatable : Component
{
    private MyDatatable ParentTableP = null;
    public  MyDatatable ParentTable
    {
        get { return MyDatatableP; }
        set { MyDatatableP=value; }
    }

    private DataColumn ParentColumnP = null;
    public  DataColum  ParentColumn 
    {
        get { return ParentColumnP; }
        set { ParentColumnP=value; }
    }

   private DataColumnCollection ColumnsP = null;
   public  DataColumnCollection Columns
   {
       get { return ColumnsP; }
       set { ColumnsP=value; }
   }
}
```

I compiled the project and add the toolbox for another project.
I am adding component to a form.
I want to that after I set a Mydatatable component parenttable property
from propertygrid, ParentColumn listing  in the property grid from parenttable columns

Comment: OK - you can add code to the `ParentTable` setter to change the `ParentColumn` value, can't you? Or change the `ParentColumn` getter to read from the table, say. What's the problem?

Comment: There is no column name in propertygrid for ParentColumn property

Comment: @Sabri Kaplan,  `[Browsable(true)]` put this attribute on top of your property definition.It shall appear in Property Grid

Comment: Furqan [Browsable(true)] for visiblty in propertygrid.My proplem getting column names from Parenttable columns.I can not explain.
my english zero :)